# Why is my equal not working on 2 identical String

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm using postgresql 13 and I'm trying to fetch data from a table based on one of its column.

Said table is defined as follow :

```sql
create table my_table (
    my_table_id int8 not null, 
    value varchar(255) not null, 
    another_table_id int8 not null, 
    primary key (my_table_id) );

create index my_table__lower_value__idx 
ON my_table USING btree (lower((value)::text));
```

Now, when I'm running both query :

- first to select a row with a where clause based on a value defined in another table (column `my_table_id`)
- second to select the same row and the same table based on a value defined in this table (column `value`).

Second query is not returning any row.

See below :

```sh
db > select * from my_table where my_table_id = 1001;  
my_table_id |  value | another_table_id  
------------+--------+-----------------
     1      | value1 |      1001  
(1 row)

db > select * from my_table where lower(value) = lower('value1');  
my_table_id |  value | another_table_id  
------------+--------+-----------------  
(0 rows)
```

Mind you, if I ran this query with some other values, it works :

```sh
db > select * from my_table where my_table_id = 1002;  
my_table_id |  value | another_table_id  
------------+--------+-----------------
     2      | value2 |      1002  
(1 row)

db > select * from my_table where lower(value) = lower('value2');  
my_table_id |  value  | another_table_id  
------------+---------+-----------------  
     2      |  value2 |      1002  
(1 row)
```

Why this difference ?

What I've tried so far :

- using `select * from my_table where value in (select value from my_table where another_table_id = 1001);` does not work
- using lower on each part of equal statement: still not working on first case.
- using LIKE keyword : it works fine in both cases

Comment: Some trailing whitespace maybe? What does `where lower(trim(value)) = lower('value1');` return?

Comment: Did this work in the past? Have you updated/upgraded the OS recently? Have you tried reindexing the `index my_table__lower_value__idx` index?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, an update was performed on the database itself (from postgresql 9.6 to 13). I didn't try to reindex the index, yet. I might give it a try soon.

For your information, I've managed to "fix" it by updated value to uppercase :
`update my_table set value = upper(value) where my_table_id = 1001`. Setting it back to lower still work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , it works ! But it does not seem to use the index.

Answer (score 0):

Reindex the table resolved the issue for me.

`REINDEX TABLE <table name>;`

But not sure why the index causes this kind of issue.